# Data table design layout

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, datatable

I am using  [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/index) plugin.I want to change the design of the table header is such a way that the table pagination should show in the table header as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from [here](http://datatables.net/usage/options). The variable sDom  is used for positioning of table elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the plugin, but probably it has a CSS folder with CSS inside it. You can modify them to do whatever you want.